# Questions and answers module Drupal 6

Tags: 6

Are there any modules for questions and answers website in Drupal 6? I want it to have theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Answers module](http://drupal.org/project/answers) should do the trick:

> Answers provides a question & answer service. Users can post questions and other users can answer them.
>
> ...
>
> The displays are based on standard CCK node displays and Views, so can be themed in the typical ways.

Comment: When I put it in the modules, in modules page it gives me: `Depends on: Features (missing), Menu (enabled), Nodereference_count (missing), Nodereference_url (missing), Number (missing), Search (disabled), Statistics (disabled), Strongarm (missing), Views_attach (missing), Votingapi (missing), Vud_node (missing)`

Comment: @PHP_guy That's Drupal's way of telling you that the module is dependent on some other modules...if you look on the Answers module page there's a list of them (all of the ones you've listed)...you need to download each of those and put them in site/all/modules as well, then you can install the Answers module :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :) The last question, how can I change theme? I want to create unique theme by myself. Thanks again.

Comment: plus, there is no module named Vud_node. :(

Comment: That one is part of [Vote Up/Down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down), admittedly it's a bit confusing :)

Comment: For theming you'll need to have a look at the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) which should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @Cliver: How can I make it, so this Q&A website could be accessed in http://localhost/qa_site, not in localhost. Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: put your Drupal installation in a sub folder of the web root folder called "qa_site", then go to sites/default/settings.php and change the `$base_url` variable to `'http://localhost/qa_site'`. That should do it

Comment: But if I already have Drupal website in localhost and want Q&A website in localhost/qa_site and I don't want to install and download drupal again?

Comment: You can't I'm afraid, if you want a separate website for the Q&A it'll have to be a separate installation of Drupal

Comment: But you can create a new page by writing nameofmodule_page somehow, is it really impossible?

Comment: You could try installing Pathauto and setting up aliases from (for example) "questions" to "qa_site/questions" (same for "answers" to "qa_site/answers") and set up automatic aliases for the "question" and "answer" content types to have "qa_site" in the url...is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I think. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions that might possibly help:

- There's a Drupal **distribution** for it ... (not just a 'module'), i.e [ArrayShift](https://www.drupal.org/project/arrayshift). Quote from its project page:

  > A question/answer site built to emulate the core functionality of the StackOverflow.com site and the StackExchange platform.
- There is a Drupal **theme** for it, i.e the [ArrayShift Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/as_theme). Here is a screenshot (from its project pages):

[image]

**Note**: Refer to my answer in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11566/module-for-creating-a-site-similar-to-stack-exchange-sites/154288#154288 for more details about a roadmap for future releases of this ArrayShift.

Disclosure: I'm the (new) maintainer of this distribution,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).